How can I delete split APKs from my bundle on Android?
I'm using Play Asset Delivery to download my game assets, which I decompress from the install-time asset pack directly into my app's sandbox file system. After I've decompressed the asset packs, I no longer need them and would like to delete them to save space on the device. Is there a way to do that with AssetManager or PackageManager or some other class?

Unclear if relevant: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java#remove-asset-pack

That's a way to get the file name, but then how would I delete it?
